Regarding upper limits to PCIE switching
I am quite new to the PCIE and want to understand following

Is there any upperlimit with respect to how many lanes that can be supported in a PCIE-switch chip ?
Can I have 512 lanes in a PCIE-switch and then support 30 GPUs with 16 lanes allocated per GPU using PCIE GEN 5.0?


From a protocol point of view, there is no real limit, but you run into problems building actual hardware, so really wide configurations are usually not built, and no connectors for it are specified, because no one would build them.
The upstream port of your switch would need to be connected to a reasonably wide root complex. I would expect that no root complex exists that is faster than the memory connected to it, and this will be your main bottleneck.

The question is asking if a PCIe Gen 5.0 switch supports up to 512 lanes.
The other answer mentions problems building actual hardware with that many lanes.
From a quick search for available PCIe Gen 5.0 switches:

The Broadcom PEX89144 supports 144-lanes and 72-ports.
The Microchip PM50100 supports 100 lanes and 52 ports.

The question contains the tag fpga. Looking at Xilinx (now AMD) FPGA support for PCIe only the Versal architecture supports Gen 5.0. For Versal the maximum number of lanes is on CPM5 which supports 2 x Gen5x8 or 16 lanes. A FPGA will need transceivers and some hard IP to support PCIe. Therefore, it is unlikely for a FPGA to be designed with sufficient transceivers and hard IP to support more PCIe lanes than a dedicated PCIe switch chip.

Thanks for the reply @Chester. So technically we cant just bump the bandwidth of a PCIE switch to accommodate more number of GPUs. So the only other option would be Ethernet/Infiniband then

@codingfreak, that wide pipe will still need to connect somewhere on the other end -- if you terminate all of it in the same memory controller, you will be limited by the bandwidth and latency of the memory connected to that. If your application saturates an x16 link (i.e. if link bandwidth actually matters here), your memory will be the bottleneck. If your application does not saturate the link, then it is fully okay to use a switch with fewer uplink lanes.

Thanks for the reply @SimonRichter. Correct me if I am wrong but why will i need wide root complex if I am not doing PCIE fanout ? Lets say we are doing PCIE fabric mode to connect multiple xPUs which can talk with each other directly without much involvement of CPU

@codingfreak, if they are talking to each other, they will use the switches only, and the packets will not reach the root complex, so indeed the upstream connection does not matter -- so a standard switch with a few x16 downstream ports is fine. On a typical PC, the root complex does not support device-to-device transfers (only some server chipsets do), so all your xPUs need to be located below a switch.
